# XSLT - Rendering HTML instead of displaying tags

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, exist-db

I have followed through some of the threads discussing ouput escaping in XSLT but none seesm to address the problem am having. I have a Rich Text Editor(RTE) that generates content with tags encoded e.g.

```
&lt;span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);" xmlns=""&gt; data 
 data  data&lt;/span&gt;  data  data  data
data  data  data  data  data
data  data  data  data &lt;span style="background-color: rgb(128, 192, 255);"&gt; data  data
data&lt;/span&gt;
```

When it comes to rendering the content on browser on a container such as `<div>` tag, I am using xslt *copy-of* method but this seems to jus display the content literally as in `<span>data data</span>` but not rendering the tags within such as `data data` as I would want. I have tried *disable-output-escaping=yes* while using *value-of* yet still no bueno :(. I Would really appreciate any help in this one having scoured the web and nothing seems to work for me so far. Thanks

SETUP-
eXist XML DB 1.5 trunk & XSLT version 2

Comment: You really need to add your XML *and* XSLT or nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

disable-output-escaping should help as long as the XSLT processor supports it and serializes the result tree. I am not familiar with exist, which XSLT 2.0 processor does it use?